# Robot Framework doesn't find element correctly by xpath

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Robot framework doesn't identify the element by xpath.

Following is the code

```
<div id="sticky-actions-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 100px;"><section class="content-header" id="sticky-actions" style="">
    <h1>Curriculum</h1>

    <div class="breadcrumb save-message hidden">
        <label class="text-success">
            <i class="flaticon flaticon-circle-check"></i>
            Saved <span>a few seconds ago</span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="row p-t-15">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-task-btn" disabled="">Create New Task</button>

            <div class="btn-group m-r-15">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle add-statement-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                    Create <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="0" class="add-curriculum-btn">Curriculum</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="0" class="add-learning-area-btn hidden">Learning Area</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="0" class="add-topic-btn hidden">Topic</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="0" class="add-outcome-btn hidden">Outcome</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-xs blue link-statements-btn" disabled="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Link selected statements">
                <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section></div>
```

**Xpath I used to for find "Create" button:**

```
xpath=//*[@id="sticky-actions-sticky-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div/button

xpath=//*[@id="sticky-actions"]/div[2]/div/div/button[.//text() = 'Create']
```

**Robot Framework step:**

```
click element  xpath=//*[@id="sticky-actions-sticky-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div/button
```

**Error:-**

```
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//*[@id="sticky-actions-sticky-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div/button' did not match any elements.
```

Comment: Can you check if there are any frame, as locators look like good Also you can put some wait function to find this element

Answer (score 4):

According to your XML, there is a `section` element inside the first `div` which you didn't include in your XPath. It should work if you add it:

```
//*[@id="sticky-actions-sticky-wrapper"]/section/div[2]/div/div/button
```

or

```
//*[@id="sticky-actions"]/div[2]/section/div/div/button[.//text() = 'Create']
```